# How to disable Telerik MVC Grid sorting, Filtering, Grouping when no records found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I need to disable Sorting, Filtering, Grouping functionality when the model comes with no records. I googled a lot. But i didn't find any solution. Pls anyone can tell me the possibilities that how i can do it ..

Comment: Ask [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/support.aspx)

Comment: @Forty-Two: They don't support it anymore (it's become part of KendoUI). And even while they were supporting it, the support for it was horrific.

Comment: @Dheyv, please show some code for your grid so that I can help you.